# how to write a query to suppress consecutive repeating values in resultset columns?

Tags: php, mysql

**I need to make repeated values be empty or null under Column Name (TGroup_Name),when selecting Table**

**For Example:**

In below table Column Name(TGroup_Name) having repeated values (ED_1) in two rows. So i want to make null or empty second row value(ED_1).But should not affect entire row.

```
TGID    TParent_Group_ID    TGroup_Name TGroup_Type TEID    TEmp_Group_ID   TEmp_Name   TEmp_Type
1              0                MD            G      10           1           Mallik        GH
10             1                ED_1          G       5          10           Thevan        GH
10             1                ED_1          G       7          10           Gupta          U
11             1                ED_2          G      11          11           Dinesh        GH
```

Comment: `UPDATE table SET TGroup_NAME = '' Tgroup_Name = ED_1 LIMIT 9999999999 OFFSET 1`

Comment: @Michael, it's probably unwise to trash the user raw data to achieve a report formatting effect.

Comment: You should show the `SELECT` that generates your sample output, and ideally a sample of what you'd like the output to look like

Answer (score 1):

Most developers think it's best to suppress such consecutive repeating values in their result sets using application-side procedural code (like Java or PHP).

But you can do it in the MySQL variant of SQL like this (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/691f5/4/0).

```
SELECT TGID,
       TParent,
       IF(Group_ID=@PREV,'',@PREV:=Group_ID) AS Group_ID,
       TGroup_Name
  FROM TABLE1,
       (SELECT @PREV:='xxxx') AS i
 ORDER BY TABLE1.TGID
```

The `IF` combined with the running value of `@prev` suppresses consecutive duplicates. The extra `(SELECT...)` subquery serves to initialize `@prev`.

This is a tricky business to get right. For example, if you just say `ORDER BY TGID` instead of what I have shown it will come out wrong. It's also entirely nonportable to other makes and models of table server.

Comment: Setting & reading a variable in a Mysql select statement is undefined behaviour. It just happens to work in certain expressions in certain implementations.